# Log 'RTD' Value Changes in Another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some issues finding an answer for this.

In Sheet1, I have a range of cells ("A4:Q4") that all have certain RTD functions in them, where they are gathering real time stock data from an outside program. These cells update every few seconds, depending on the changes from the parent program.

What I want to do, is have it so that every time any value in that range changes (ie. everytime the RTD values update), copy that range's values and paste them to the next available empty row in Sheet2. This should effectively create a long list of values, but I'm having an issue with the RTD stuff. My current code will do what I want, but only if the values in the range are changed manually, NOT when the RTD values get updated. Even when the RTD values are updating/changing, it's not copying those new values over to Sheet2, if that makes sense. It would seem it has something to do with the macro not realizing that the values are changing automatically. When I make my own changes to the values in that range, it works, but that renders the RTD functions in the cells useless.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:Q4")

    ' Wait for change to happen...
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then


    ' once change happens, copy the range (yes keep R4 value too)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:R4").Copy

    ' Paste it into the next empty row of Sheet2
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Dim NextRow As Range
        Set NextRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

End If
End Sub
```

I'm thinking a potential solution would be to make a loop where by it stores each value in that range, and then every half a second or 1 second it would compare the stored values to the "current" values and see if there's any change. If there is, copy that range's values to Sheet2. But this seems clunky.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The Worksheet Change event doesn't fire when a cell changes value due to formula recalculation. You can use the Worksheet Calculate event for that. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) the documentation.

Comment: @BigBen Great! Would you recommend something other than my intersect function to monitor for the changes?

Comment: I think you're referring to the fact that the Calculate event doesn't have a `Target` argument? Pretty sure there are examples here on SO of how to do it - basically you  populate an array with the original values of `A4:Q4` when the workbook opens, with the Workbook Open event. Then in the Calculate event, compare the new values to the previous. If anything changed, copy to sheet2, then update the array with the new values.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks. I'm not very knowledgeable with arrays or how to compare them to one another. I've made an update in my original question above declaring individual variables (as that's what I know how to do) along the lines of what I think you're suggesting, but when I ran it again, it copy and pastes about 80 rows of the same thing into Sheet2. I only need one per change. Hope you still have some insight. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If 2 or more cells change simultaneously, should the row get copied more than once to sheet 2?

Comment: @BigBen I would say, if 2 cells change simultaneously, it could be copied over only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the Worksheet.Change event doesn't fire when a cell changes value due to formula recalculation. So you can use the Worksheet.Calculate event.

Unlike the Worksheet.Change event, there is no `Target` in the Worksheet.Calculate event. You can test that a cell within your specific range has recalculated using the following:

---

1. In the `ThisWorkbook` code module:

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       PopulateKeyValueArray
   End Sub
   ```
2. In the `Sheet1` code module:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

       On Error GoTo SafeExit
       Application.EnableEvents = False

       Dim keyCells As Range
       Set keyCells = Me.Range("A4:Q4")

       Dim i As Long
       For i = 1 To UBound(KeyValues, 2)
           If keyCells(, i).Value <> keyValues(1, i) Then

               Dim lastRow As Long
               With Sheet2
                   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                   .Range("A" & lastRow & ":R" & lastRow).Value =   Me.Range("A4:R4").Value
               End With

               Exit For
           End If
       Next i

   SafeExit:
       PopulateKeyValueArray
       Application.EnableEvents = True
   End Sub
   ```
3. In a normal code module:

   ```
   Public keyValues()

   Public Sub PopulateKeyValueArray()
       keyValues = Sheet1.Range("A4:Q4").Value
   End Sub
   ```

---

(1): `keyValues` is a `Public` array that is populated with the values in `keyCells` when the workbook first opens.

(2): When any cell changes due to formula recalculation in `Sheet1`, the values in `keyCells` are compared one-by-one to their corresponding element in `keyValues`. If there is a difference, i.e. a cell in `keyCells` has been updated, then the latest values in `A4:R4` are written to the next available row in `Sheet2`. The `Exit For` ensures that this value transfer only happens once, even if multiple cells have changed. Finally, `keyValues` is updated with the latest values in `keyCells`.

(3): `PopulateKeyValueArray` reads the values from `Sheet1:Range("A4:Q4")` into the `keyValues` array.

Note that `keyValues` will be empty when you first add the code to your workbook, so either save and re-open, or run `PopulateKeyValueArray` to populate the array.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, but I'm still having an issue. I've updated my question above with screenshots, but now when I first open the workbook, and manually make a change just to simulate a changing RTD cell, I get an error Out of Stack Space, and then when I click debug it pastes it 82 times into Sheet2 :O I double checked that I have all of the codes in their proper modules as well.

Comment: I saw your update. Do you have any code in the sheet2 code module?

Comment: Negative. Only Sheet1, ThisWorkbook and a module with the appropriate code segments. I don't know if it matters, but I'm also copying the time over from Sheet1 with is the value in cell R4, but that is not one of the cells being monitored in the range, just one that gets copied so I don't imagine that's it?

Comment: It's actually because of that. I assume the formula in `R4` is `=NOW()`? I'll make an edit.

Comment: Oh god, sorry about that. Yes R4 is =NOW()

Comment: Worked! Thanks a million for all your help. I'll give this solution the mark as the answer. My only concern is that, the RTD is stalled for the night as it's stock data that I'm pulling and the markets are closed so the RTD data isn't streaming (much) during the evening, so first thing tomorrow morning I'll confirm that the RTD updates are copying over, and not just me manually changing the Sheet1.Range values to test like I am now. If you don't hear back from me, it works! Thanks again, you taught me a lot from your solution!

Comment: Happy coding! Glad to help.