# Worksheet.Calculate_Cell Change Copy Adjacent Cell Text

Tags: excel, vba, logging, worksheet-function, rtd

[image]

The Apple & Orange Volume are constantly changing values and I need to copy the adjacent Buy/Sell cells once the volume changes. I know I need a Worksheet_Calculate script to do this can you help me start it out? So if a volume of an Apple went from 10 to 11 (in I2) the Worksheet_Calculate function targets that change and logs in another cell that the change was a Buy (in J2) for the change in Apple volume (in I2). Same logic applys to the Oranges.

Comment: Are the values in column I formulas, or hard-coded values?

Comment: They are RTD formulas so they come in as none number values. To get around that I can just simply +0 to the formula to make them identifiable as a true number if that is necessary for the script to work.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` doesn't fire on formula recalculation. You probably need to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for catching that. Could you help me get the script started for a quick test?

Comment: I wrote an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622486/log-rtd-value-changes-in-another-worksheet) a while back.

Comment: Yes, this is very similar logic that I was looking for. Thanks very much for leading me towards a solution. Let me review, test, upload the script to my question, you can review, and then get additonal credit that you desire for helping folks out that need your expertise. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Hi @BigBen yes this script is similar except I am looking at the I2:I9 and Y2:Y9 w/ the changing RTD values and need to record whether that is a Buy or Sell (in columns J2:J9 & W2:W9) transaction (non-RTD value just a regular function). So the changing RTDs are in I & Y columns and the logs I need to record are in J & W columns. The Q/A you refered to is only for one row as I need multiple columns/rows to record.